# Reading Environment variables from config json in Angular does not work when Auth0 cachelocation is set to "localstorage"

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, safari, auth0

I am trying to get environment variables in Angular from a config.json which will be set at my ApiService constructor while running in docker. As soon as I set the Auth0 Cachelocation to "localstorage" (because of the known Safari ITP problem) the environment variables weren't set. Running without "cachelocation = localstorage" works fine.

Here's my `api.service.ts`-constructor:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config: ConfigService
  ) {
    if(this.config.environment && this.config.environment.API_SERVER) { // reading with webpack on local dev machine -> works!
      this.baseUrl = this.config.environment.API_SERVER;
    }
    else {
      this.config.getConfigJson().subscribe((result: any) => this.baseUrl = result.API_SERVER);
      console.log(this.baseUrl) // -> undefined (while running in docker and using localstorage)
    }
  }
```